# Manual alternative to mod_deflate

Tags: apache, compression, module

Say I don't have mod_deflate compiled into apache, and I don't feel like recompiling right now. What are the downsides to a manual approach, e.g. something like:

```
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING} gzip
RewriteRule ^/css/styles.css$ /css/styles.css.gz
```

*(Note: I'm aware that the specifics of that RewriteCond need to be tweaked **slightly**)*

Comment: You realize this means every time you change any file, you will have to make sure to generate the gzipped version, or you risk either (1) having the gzipped users being served an older version of the file or (2) randomly 404ing if the gzipped version hasn't been made yet.  Just one mistake, and all of a sudden you have a Heisenbug that's very tough to track down.

Comment: Yes - the specific use case here is just for a very small number of rarely changing files, so although that's still certainly a disadvantage with this approach, it's probably not a show-stopper. I've considered adding a "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f" to the chain, but there's then a concern about the inefficiencies of constant file stats (I'm not sure how/if apache caches that info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative would be to forward everything to a PHP script, which gzips and caches everything on the fly. On every request, it would compare timestamps with the cached version and return that if it's newer than the source file. With PHP, you can also overwrite the HTTP Headers, so it is treated properly as if it was GZIPed by Apache itself.

Something like this might do the job for you:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(css/styles.css)$ cache.php?file=$1 [L]
```

cache.php:

```
<?php
// Convert path to a local file path (may need to be tweaked)
cache($_GET['file']);

// Return cached or raw file (autodetect)
function cache($file)
{
  // Regenerate cache if the source file is newer
  if (!is_file($file.'.gz') or filemtime($file.'.gz') < filemtime($file)) {
    write_cache($file);
  }

  // If the client supports GZIP, send compressed data
  if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']) and strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') !== false) {
    header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
    readfile($file.'.gz');
  } else { // Fallback to static file
    readfile($file);
  }
  exit;
}

// Saved GZIPed version of the file
function write_cache($file)
{
  copy($file, 'compress.zlib://'.$file.'.gz');
}
```

You will need write permissions for apache to generate the cached versions. You can modify the script slightly to store cached files in a different place.

This hasn't been extensively tested and it might need to be modified slightly for your needs, but the idea is all there and should be enough to get you started.

Comment: You probably want to flip that greater-than sign into a less-than sign. Other than that, looks good.

Comment: Yeah, my reference to a server-side script in an earlier comment was me thinking along those lines. Great use of 'compress.zlib://', though; I hadn't come across that before.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a big performance difference between the manual and automatic approaches. I did some apache-bench runs with automatic and manual compression and both times were within 4% of each other.

The obvious downside is that you'll have to manually compress the CSS files before deploying. The other thing you might want to make very sure is that you've got the configurations right. I couldn't get wget to auto-decode the css when I tried the manual approach and ab reports also listed the compressed data size instead of uncompressed ones as with automatic compression.

Comment: The manual compression might not be so much an issue - in this case, I'm dealing with files that rarely change, and there's a /possibility/ that the compression could be automated via a server-side script.
The info from wget is very useful, though - thanks for the research. I guess I'm going to have to test this myself if I'm actually going to use it, but great info on the performance difference - many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [mod_ext_filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ext_filter.html) and pipe things through gzip. In fact, it's one of the examples:

```
# mod_ext_filter directive to define the external filter
ExtFilterDefine gzip mode=output cmd=/bin/gzip

<Location /gzipped>
# core directive to cause the gzip filter to be
# run on output
SetOutputFilter gzip

# mod_header directive to add
# "Content-Encoding: gzip" header field
Header set Content-Encoding gzip
</Location>
```

The advantage of this is that it's really, really easy… The disadvantage is that there will be an additional `fork()` and `exec()` on each request, which will obviously have a small impact on performance.